# Каков ресурс перезаписи у обычной оперативной памяти?

Tags: память, железо

Появилась надобность часто перезаписывать огромное количество данных. В худшем случае размер этих данных составляет 320 * 240 4-байтовых чисел, а перезаписывать их надо 60 раз в секунду (т.е. 60 раз в секунду перезаписывать 76800 переменных, и это, хотя и худший случай, может быть больше). Программа будет работать около 3 часов.
Стоит ли бояться за оперативку? Я, конечно, знаю, что у неё почти бесконечное кол-во циклов перезаписи, но мало ли.

Comment: Ничего не бойтесь. Будьте смелым.

Comment: @Igor спасибо за мотивацию, но с такой смелостью у меня есть шанс остаться ни с чем

Comment: А мне вопрос нравится, только чуть-чуть его поправил бы. +1

Comment: Оперативная память в компьютерах динамическая. Это значит что она способна хранить информацию несколько десятков миллисекунд. По истечении этого срока специальная схема считывает всю память и записывает её обратно. С частотой 10-100 раз в секунду. Вне зависимости от того чем занят ваш компьютер он десять раз в секунду переписывает всю память. Всю. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если мы говорим про DRAM - ресурс практически бесконечный. Т.к. к памяти нет требования по хранению информации в случае пропадания питания, никакого износа не происходит (как например у EEPROM или SSD). На железном уровне - каждый бит это крошечный конденсатор (с зарядом или без), подзаряжаемый каждые сколько-то тактов.

> DRAM uses tiny capacitors to temporarily store data, these are continuously refreshed by the memory controller because these capacitors leak. Both DRAM and SRAM will work until material degradation renders the part unusable. (decades)

*// https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/370647/4752*